# Same value for SQL input prompt in multiple locations and JOIN issue

Tags: sql, oracle, join, user-input

I'm trying to create a report for a customer that is specific to whatever date range they're needing at the current time, but I'm having a couple issues.

The biggest one is, how do I get my user input prompts for `Enter_Start_Date` and `Enter_End_Date` to only appear once each? (ie Start: 01-JAN-18 and End: 28-FEB-18).  I tried to research other questions on here, and there was a suggestion (that worked for that user) of doing a && with same variable name before the additional occurrences, but when I run the query, I still get prompted 4 times.

The other "problem" I'm having is the below query isn't returning the results for `parts_used` and `h_repairs` like it should.

```
SELECT
    a.h_desc,
    a.fic,
    a.p_part,
    a.d_part,
    a.nomenclature,
    a.qpe,
    SUM(b.qty) AS parts_used,
    COUNT(c.fic) AS h_repairs,
    a.cdf_ohb,
    a.bmc
FROM
    t_table_a a
    LEFT JOIN t_table_b b ON b.fic = a.fic
                                   AND b.part_no = a.d_part
                                   AND b.real_f_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('&Enter_Start_Date', 'DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('&Enter_End_Date'
                                   , 'DD-MON-YY')
    LEFT JOIN t_table_c c ON c.fic = a.fic
                             AND c.real_f_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('&&Enter_Start_Date', 'DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('&&Enter_End_Date',
                             'DD-MON-YY')
GROUP BY
    a.bmc,
    a.cdf_ohb,
    a.d_part,
    a.fic,
    a.h_desc,
    a.nomenclature,
    a.p_part,
    a.qpe
ORDER BY
    a.fic,
    a.p_part
```

When I do the above query, the `parts_used` and `h_repairs` columns are completely out of whack, but when I nest the joins like in the below query, the results populate as expected.

```
SELECT
    t.h_desc,
    t.fic,
    t.p_part,
    t.d_part,
    t.nomenclature,
    t.qpe,
    COUNT(c.fic) AS h_repairs,
    t.parts_used,
    t.cdf_ohb,
    t.bmc
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            a.h_desc,
            a.fic,
            a.p_part,
            a.d_part,
            a.nomenclature,
            a.qpe,
            SUM(b.qty) AS parts_used,
            a.cdf_ohb,
            a.bmc
        FROM
            t_table_a a
            LEFT JOIN t_table_b b ON b.fic = a.fic
                                     AND b.part_no = a.d_part
                                     AND b.real_f_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('&Enter_Start_Date', 'DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('&Enter_End_Date'
                                     , 'DD-MON-YY')
        GROUP BY
            a.bmc,
            a.cdf_ohb,
            a.d_part,
            a.fic,
            a.h_desc,
            a.nomenclature,
            a.p_part,
            a.qpe
    ) t
    LEFT JOIN t_table_c c ON c.fic = t.fic
                             AND c.real_f_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('&&Enter_Start_Date', 'DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('&&Enter_End_Date',
                             'DD-MON-YY')
GROUP BY
    t.h_desc,
    t.fic,
    t.p_part,
    t.d_part,
    t.nomenclature,
    t.qpe,
    t.parts_used,
    t.cdf_ohb,
    t.bmc
ORDER BY
    t.fic,
    t.p_part
```

Is nesting the joins what needs to happen, or am I doing something a little wrong?

Comment: I'm also using SQL Developer when running these queries, so I don't know if that has anything to do with the double prompting for same variables.  But realized that may be a useful piece of information too.

Comment: You should probably ask that as two questions; for the second part you will need to supply sample data, current results and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You've only changed the second reference to each substitution variable from `&` to `&&`. If you change all of them then you'll only be prompted once for each. (Not sure why it does that, but SQL*Plus does the same).

You can also prompt with a nicer message by adding these statements to you script before your query:

```
accept Enter_Start_Date date format "DD-MON-YY" prompt "Enter the start date in the format 'DD-MON-YY'" 
accept Enter_End_Date date format "DD-MON-YY" prompt "Enter the end date in the format 'DD-MON-YY'"
```

As that defines the variables too, you can then use either a sing `&` or a double `&&` when you refer to them (and you can use shorter names; and your own prompt text of course).

---

If you can I'd also suggest you choose a different date format, something which doesn't rely on the user's session date language (as the month abbreviations are NLS-dependent), preferably using 4-digit years, and which is unambiguous - so maybe YYYY-MM-DD instead of DD/MM/YYYY, though users could find that awkward I suppose. (That would also let you use date literals as bonus if you wanted to). As the prompt can contain the format you expect they at least know what they should enter, but they still might not like it.